# From what legal tradition do the long "whereas" motivation clauses of the EU legislation come?

Tags: european-union

Practically all EU non-treaty legislation and regulations have pretty long "whereas" clauses, often pages long, introducing the context and often the motivation of the legislation/regulations.

From which country's (if any) legal or legislative tradition are these detailed "whereas" clauses inherited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These clauses are called [recitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recital_(law)).  Taken together, they are a form of [preamble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preamble).

The tradition of preambles is quite ancient.  The [Code of Hammurabi](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/ancient/hamframe.asp), for example, has a preamble.  This preamble serves to establish the authority of the one enacting the laws, however, rather than his motivation.

United Nations instruments typically use a series of participial phrases as [preambular paragraphs (pdf)](https://www.un.org/ar/ga/pdf/Guidelines%20for%20editing%20of%20draft%20proposals.pdf) rather than subordinate clauses, but they have the same function of establishing context and motivation.

I have not been able to locate the origin of this particular form of preamble, however.  It seems to have evolved gradually from freely constructed preambles.  I could not identify when this form became fixed.

Comment: I suspect that might have an origin in some continental practice (French, German etc.) On the other hand, the UN document allows for "Taking into account" which is basically just a more wordy equivalent of "whereas"

Comment: @Fizz I don't think it's exclusively continental, though.  Look at the [Act of Union 1707](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Act_of_Union_1707), the [US Bill of Rights](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/United_States_Bill_of_Rights), and the English [Bill of Rights of 1689](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bill_of_Rights_1689), the first word of which is "whereas."

Comment: They are common in deeds and contracts as well